# Git - Independent Branches or Different repos for instances of the same program with slightly different use

Tags: git, branch, organization, project-organization

I recently started using git and have a question. I have two branches of a program, one which uses algorithm A and one which uses algorithm B. These algorithms do the same thing differently. Now, for each of these two branches I want to make different instances of the program which run for different sort of data (these can be up to 50 different instances). Before you ask, I can't incorporate them all in the same program because of complexity and performance issues.

Additionally, if possible, I would like to be able to modify the core (i.e. the part of the source that is shared between all instances) and all instances to be updated with the change.

What method would you recommend to achieve that?

PS: Since my question may not be very clear, feel free to ask for any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they do the same thing differently, try to make them conform to a common interface/API.  If you can do that, then apply the Bridge pattern  The two implementations can just live in different subdirectories.  You don't really need git or branches do manage this--just have two different implementations of behind the Bridge and choose the correct impl at runtime (or compile-time, as it seems you prefer the compile-time approach).

Comment: Hey, I liked your idea. I'm writing in C and I made different header files for the different program uses. My only concern is it looks kinda messy cause I have to put the function definitions in these header files to be able to make them inline.

Comment: Without really seeing what you're doing, I would make one header file and have different .c (and, thus, .o) files that get linked in depending on the job you're trying to accomplish.  That would be for compile-time bridge implementation.  For a run-time bridge, there would be a thin universal implementation of the API that would simply forward/delegate the call to the real implementation switched in at runtime.

Comment: Yes, that was my plan but `inline` requires that the function be defined in the same translation unit as it is being used, so I have to define them in the header file and then a .c file is not more of use. Of course I haven't checked yet what kind of performance improvement the `inline` instruction provides, if any!

Comment: "inline" is only a suggestion to the compiler; compilers are free to ignore the suggestion.  Thus, I prefer to craft clean, maintainable code backed by sound architecture.  That's not to suggest that there is no room at design time for optimization, but the types of optimizations that happen at design time often have to do with algorithm choice or data structure choice, and not with whether a body of code is inline or has function call overhead.

Comment: If the reason you want to inline something is because it's called in a tight loop on the critical path, then consider moving the loop inside the bridge implementation rather than outside the bridge implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a master branch with the core code and 2 other branches with alg and alg B so you merge master to your algorithm branches. That way you can have two different programs that have a different algorithm but the same core. I dont really understand what you mean by instances